# QUERY help for a learning SQL admin

Tags: sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT count(*) from
(
SELECT custid, count(*) as OrderCount
FROM orderinfo
WHERE preparedate between '2011-06-01' and '2011-12-31'
GROUP by CUSTID
) COUNTDB
WHERE Ordercount > '20'
```

Returns:  901 CustID's

If I run:

```
SELECT * from
(
SELECT custid, count(*) as OrderCount
FROM orderinfo
WHERE preparedate between '2011-06-01' and '2011-12-31'
GROUP by CUSTID
) COUNTDB
WHERE Ordercount > '20'
```

It returns a list of the individual CustID's and their order counts.

```
custid OrderCount
1001   24
1010   30
1033   36
```

...

What I am hoping to do is see how many of these returned customer ID's from the query, have placed an order in a later date range, say '2012-06-01' and '2012-12-31'

**My goal would be:**

Let me see if I can describe this another way.

I need to see the total count of CustID's that have placed more than 20 orders in 2011 (provided date range).  Then, the second step would be to see how many of those SAME customers have placed an order in 2012 date range of the same days

Comment: You should not use BETWEEN with dates. http://database.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/sql-server-l/using-between-operator-for-datetime-range-2795017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Let me see if I can describe this another way. I need to see the total
>   count of CustID's that have placed more than 20 orders in 2011
>   (provided date range). Then, the second step would be to see how many
>   of those SAME customers have placed an order in 2012 date range of the
>   same days @AlexandreP.Levasseur

Please try this. Also, it would be handy if you could make an SQLFiddle for us to test our queries when trying to help you !

```
SELECT
    CustId
FROM
    OrderInfo
WHERE
    PrepareDate BETWEEN '2012-06-01' and '2012-12-31' AND
    CustId IN 
        (SELECT
            DISTINCT CustId
        FROM
            OrderInfo
        WHERE
            PrepareDate BETWEEN '2011-06-01' and '2011-12-31'
        GROUP BY
            CustId
        HAVING
            Count(*) > 20)
```

Comment: So if I change to select count(distinct CustID) than that reports 697 Customer ID's that placed more than 20 orders in 2011, and at least one order in 2012, correct?  If that is the case, my number looks good and I you got it!

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming your schema looks like this:

```
OrderInfo ( CustId, PrepareDate )
```

(hmm, simple, eh?)

So if I understand you correctly, you want the list of customers who have placed an order between two dates AND they've placed more than 20 orders. That's simple enough:

```
SELECT
    CustId,
    Count(*) AS OrderCount
FROM
    OrderInfo
WHERE
    PrepareDate BETWEEN '2012-06-01' and '2012-12-31'
GROUP BY
    CustId
HAVING
    OrderCount > 20
```

Comment: Yes. This is because the order of the operations in this query is FROM, WHERE, GROUP BY, SELECT and then HAVING. In the WHERE expression the alias `OrderCount` is not yet known so it cannot be applied as you wanted it to be.

Comment: Let me see if I can describe this another way.
I need to see the total count of CustID's that have placed more than 20 orders in 2011 (provided date range).  Then, the second step would be to see how many of those SAME customers have placed an order in 2012 date range of the same days @AlexandreP.Levasseur

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some like this Works:

```
SELECT
   custid
FROM
   orderinfo
WHERE
     preparedate between '2011-06-01' and '2011-12-31'
 AND custid IN (
       SELECT
          custid
       FROM
          orderinfo
       WHERE
            preparedate between '2011-06-01' and '2011-12-31'
       GROUP BY
          custid
       HAVING
          COUNT(*) > 20
 )
```